# EF 6 Join a Table with Subquery result

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have below SQL query

```
select M.* from Department M
join 
    (select StudentId,max(Created) Created from Department
    where Type = 'New'
    group by StudentId
    ) 
    A
on M.StudentId= A.StudentId AND M.Created = A.Created
```

for this i have created below EF linq

```
(from mmfcl in _Context.Department
      join filtermmfcl in ( _Context.Department
                           .Where(mmfcl => mmfcl.Type == "New")
                           .GroupBy(mmfcl => mmfcl.StudentId)
                           .Select(mmfcl => new 
                           {
                              StudentId= mmfcl.Key,
                              Date = mmfcl.Max(cl => cl.Created)
                           }).ToList()
                          )
     on new { mmfcl.StudentId, mmfcl.Created } equals 
        new { filtermmfcl.StudentId, filtermmfcl.Date }
     Select mmfcl);
```

Using this query i am getting compile time error near Join keyword.

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this.
Actually the issue was with on Clause.

```
new { mmfcl.StudentId, mmfcl.Created }
```

should be equal with

```
new { filtermmfcl.StudentId, filtermmfcl.Date }
```

with regards to data type and name as well.

So I changed on clause as below and is working fine

```
new { mmfcl.StudentId, mmfcl.Created } equals new { filtermmfcl.StudentId, 
filtermmfcl.Created }.
```